# How can you use a for loop to append an array in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, append

I'm trying to append an array using specific characters in the first column of a data frame for each row of the data frame.

The following code works for just the first row:

```
indx = []
ldate = data.iat[0, 0]
year = ldate[0:4]
quarter = ldate[6]
myIndex = year + " Q" + quarter
indx.append(myIndex)
```

But when I try to use a for loop to do it for each row I get and error message:

```
indx = []
for i in range(0,193):
    ldate = data.iat[0, i]
    year = ldate[0:4]
    quarter = ldate[6]
    myIndex = year + " Q" + quarter
    indx.append(myIndex)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Why can't the for loop iterate?

Comment: your error is in line `ldate = data.iat[0, i]` maybe because you don't have `data.iat[0, 1]`, ...`data.iat[0, 193] ` . You should rather use something like `for item in data:` OR maybe it should be `[i, 0]` instead of `[0, i]` because `numpy.arrays` (like matrix in math) uses `[row,column]`, not `[column,row]`

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data?

Comment: Thank you, it works with `data.iat[i, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[i, 0]` instead of `[0, i]` because `numpy.array` and `pandas.DataFrame` (like matrix in math) use `[row,column]` instead of `[column,row]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    print(df.iat[i, 0], df[i].to_list())
```

You could also use `df.iterrow()` (or `df.iteritems()`, `df.itertuples()`) to work with rows without `range()` and `i`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[0], row.to_list())
```

But in `DataFrame` you can do many things without loop

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2019  1', 1,2,3],
    ['2019  2', 4,5,6],
    ['2019  3', 7,8,9]])

result = df[0].apply(lambda x: x[:4] + " Q" + x[6])

print(result.to_list())
```

Result

```
['2019 Q1', '2019 Q2', '2019 Q3']
```

Or directly to the same DataFrame

```
df['result'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x[:4] + " Q" + x[6])

print(df)
```

Result

```
         0  1  2  3   result
0  2019  1  1  2  3  2019 Q1
1  2019  2  4  5  6  2019 Q2
2  2019  3  7  8  9  2019 Q3
```